# How would I write a function that decodes this text?

Tags: c#, encryption, decode, encode

My OS is Windows 10, I'm using Visual Studio 2019, the language is C#

My goal is to make a function that would decode the encoded text.

I do not know what encoding algorithm it uses.

Here are a few examples:

> Example 1:
>
> Encoded text = )3)6,..?1EB
>
> Decoded text = encodedtext
>
> Example 2:
>
> Encoded text = )='485/
>
> Decoded text = example

If anyone could help me, it would be really appreciated.

**Thank you in advance.**

Comment: This doesn't look like encryption.  It is encoding.  So it look like it is a mapping between characters.  For example the character ')' is the letter 'e'.

Comment: Is it that you do not know the encryption algorithm, or do you know the algorithm but not the key? In the latter case, you can at least try to brute-force.

Comment: @jdweng

But later on, the e character is /

Any ideas?

Comment: Take a look at the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) (for starters, at least; this isn't necessarily limited to ASCII). Note that it drifts; the amount it increases the character is one more each time. `e` became `)`, then two characters later, `c` became `)`. See if you can reproduce the encoding with that information, then work on the decoder.

Comment: @KlausGütter

I do not know the encoding algorithm, I am trying to figure it out and make a decoding function for it.

Comment: That should be Caesar Cipher or some other [substitution cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_cipher)...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov

It was not the Ceaser Cipher, but thanks for trying.


For the substitution cipher, I do not really know about, as I am quite new to encoding

Comment: The encoding looks like the text and the encoded text are the same number of characters.  So the algorithm is some how using previous characters(s) to encode current character.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, with the help of some other people, i wrote this and I got the encoding algorithm, now all i need to do is make the decode function :)

@AlexeiLevenkov could you unlock the thread so i could post the answer?